# Security risk: Digitally sign communications for SMB

Tags: network, certificates, windows, attacks

I have a computer (Windows) on a network where an industrial process is controlled. There is an option in Local Security Policy >> Local Policies >> Security Options >> "Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always)".

By default, this option should be Disabled on Windows machines but all computers that we receive from the vendor has this feature Enabled, so I can only assume that it is intentional. In order to backup to a NAS, I had to disable this feature.

My question is what might the security concerns be considering that this machine is on a local network where an industrial process is being controlled. From Microsoft's website, I get the impression that it prevents man-in-the-middle attacks that modify SMB packets. Is this the full story?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, Microsoft Technet lists [MITM prevention](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728025%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) as the sole use of this setting. And a [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) does just that: to prove the authenticity of a digital message. If your network is trusted and MITM scenarios are *really* (!) not possible, it can be disabled.

Apparently there's also a performance decrease involved when it's enabled. So, if you're disabling it for performance reasons: [you're trading performance for security](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2010/12/01/the-basics-of-smb-signing-covering-both-smb1-and-smb2.aspx).